# add query string to params on page load - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on some functionality involving a date range. On the page it's a list of users with some dates, and a form for the start_date and end_date. On the page, I want a query to be added to the url so the user doesnt have to hit the search button on the form, and the results are loaded on the page.

So for example a user comes to the page, and the url would look something like
`http://localhost:3000/user_and_project?at_start=2016-02-26&at_end=2016-03-10&commit=Search` and the results would be like the user clicked the button themselves.

I have found a couple things that *could* work, but nothing has done it. Currently, a solution has been to do

```
params[:at_start] ||= at_start_helper #method name
params[:at_end] ||= at_end_helper #method name
# or
@date_range = { at_start: at_start_helper, at_end: at_end_helper}
# or
params[:at_start] = at_start_helper
params[:at_end] = at_end_helper
```

but that doesnt actually add it to the url and doesn't do anything. does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this, so the solution I came up with was to make a custom `somedomain.com/user-hours` which then redirected to the previously mentioned page with the query string ready to go

```
def user_and_project
  # original method
end

def user_hours
  redirect_to(controller: 'controller_name', action: 'user_and_project', at_start: at_start_helper, at_end: at_end_helper)
end

# routes
get '/user-hours' => 'controller#action'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you need provide path like this:

```
project_path(:at_start=>"2016-02-26", :at_end => "2016-03-26")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. This action is happening from the controller so I don't have anywhere to pass a path to, and I want (if possible) the query string to be appended to the url on page load so the user doesnt have to search anything (I have methods to take care of the manual part). I havent found a way to do this, but I have to think it's possible and I'm just not doing something correctly.

Comment: @JamesN, you can pass a path to redirect method. From where do you take actual at_start and at_end values? Thing is, it is really hard to understand what are you trying to achieve. Consider this - all purpose of controller in Rails is to handle incoming request. There might me some misunderstanding.

Comment: the at_start and at_end values are coming from 2 helper methods that are formatting a date. I can pass a path, but I'm doing this logic in the controller action of the page, so if I pass a path to this action, it returns a redirect loop.

Comment: @JamesN, sorry, still don't see  logic. So user comes to page, does some input, submits, and then is redirected on same page?

Comment: I have a page that has a list of users w/ hours worked, and 2 inputs `at_start` and `at_end` w/ a search button. The functionality I am trying to achieve is when a user comes to the page instead of filling out the inputs and clicking search manually, it takes the 2 necessary dates (covered with 2 helper methods) for those inputs, appends those results to the URL, and returns the page like the user inputted those values themselves. I was able to achieve something similar using `redirect_to(at_start: at_start_helper, at_end: at_end_helper)` in the controller action, but it caused a redirect loop

Comment: @JamesN, why don't you store those values in variable then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104938/discussion-between-james-n-and-joe-half-face).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put those parameters in the link tag, so it will display on the browser url as well. Then you can used the parameters as default values to your form fields.

Like:

```
<a href="<%= my_path(:at_start=>"2016-02-26", :at_end => "2016-03-26") %>" >Test</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. unfortunately, there is no where to put a link tag as I am looking for functionality that will append those values to the url on page load.

Comment: is there no previous page rendered, before the page you want to have parameters in url?

Comment: yes, that is correct. users use the link and go right to the page. I wrote a method which encapsulates the logic via helper methods, so now I'm just trying to pass that logic to the query string in the URL